# Как делать разметку диска на Ubuntu для UEFI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uefi, disk

Пожалуйста, дайте инструкцию о том, как делать разметку диска на Ubuntu для UEFI

Comment: Google/яндекс в помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот официальная дока по этому вопросу:

https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_desktop_14_04/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%81_uefi

Проблема в том, что Ваш вопрос содержит два (очень мало связанных) понятия:

1. UEFI
2. Разметка диска

Первое - это про то, что идёт **до** загрузки ОС. А второе - это уже про **работающую** ОС.

И если Вас действительно интересует - как разметить диск для Ubuntu, то очень простой совет - создайте отдельный раздел для каталога */home* - тогда при всех апгрейдах пользовательские файлы и настройки останутся в целости.